# Related Rates Result Not Precise

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, related-rates

If I have a ladder of length $24$ feet leaned against a wall, with the foot of the ladder being $10$ feet away from the wall; and a man pulls the foot of the ladder away from the wall at $4$ feet per second, then at what rate does the end of the ladder travel down the wall?

I modeled the problem mathematic all, first: If the leg of a right triagle is stretched (at $4$ ft/s), The hypotenuse is kept constant,and the right angle is also unchanging, then at what rate will the remaining leg change? We do know that the remaining leg should diminish as the former leg is made greater. If the rate at which the first leg grows (call this length $x$ from now on) is $dx/dt = 4$; then call the remaining leg $y$, and its rate of change with respect to the same variable y should be $dy/dt$. İt is also known that the rate at which the hypotenuse change is $0$ (call it z, so $dz/dt = 0$). Since $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$, then given the initial $x = 10$, and $z = 26$; $y$ must equal $24$. Imlplicitly differentiating the equation we have, we get $2x(dx/dt) + 2y(dy/dt) = 2z(dz/dt)$. Substituting whats known, we get $dy/dt = - 80/48) = - 1.666...$; however, when I check if the answer is correct, I see that:

If $x$ grows its first increment, it become $14$ ($10 + 4$). By our calculations, at this increment, $y$ become $22.333...$ ($24 - 1.666...$); but, using the pythagorean theorem, this would mean that the hypotenuse is $26.358637...$; although this is quite close to $26$, in some problems, The answer deviates to as much as $2$ whole units. The answer, should have been at least as close as $\sqrt26^2 - 14^2$ giving $21.9089...$. Why does this deviation exist? İt is quite negligible here, but in other problem it makes quite the difference. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please do not use inappropriate tags — in this case, differential geometry.

Comment: Your ladder magically changes from 24 feet long to 26 feet long halfway through the question.

Answer (score 1):

As your computations show, the rate at which the height is dropping, $\dot y$, is not a constant.   Indeed you get $$\dot y =-\frac {4x}y$$ so it depends on the current position.  Your "paradoxical" computation incorrectly imagines that $\dot y$ stays constant for an interval of time, but it only holds instantaneously.

Comment: this is very new to me, thank you very much! Does this imply that $y$ increases negatively always, after $x$ goes beyond $26$? Is this common to all related rates problems? This wouldn't make sense in a problem such as, for example, if two points on a sphere were picked, one near the diameter, and one near the pole; as the sphere spins, one point travels a larger distance than the other. But it shouldn't be the case that as one increments constantly, the other continuously increments in speed also.

Comment: The problem changes completely after $x>26$. Before that point, you have a right triangle, and the height drops to preserve the hypotenuse.  After that, the height stops dropping.  The formula I wrote for $\dot y$ is only valid for $0<y<26$, assuming the length of the ladder to be $26$ (you have $24$ in your post).

Comment: To gain insight, you might want to solve the problem without using related rates.  You can write $x(t)=10+4t$, if you want the ladder to start with the base $10$ feet from the wall.  That means $y(t)=\sqrt {26^2-(10+4t)^2}$ where, again, that formula only holds while the ladder is still touching the wall.

Comment: thank you much for the insight! I found the motion most beautiful! Although, if forget the ladder problem, and only consider the triangle; wouldn't the formula still make sense mathematically, even after $y$ goes beyond $0$? Wouldn't this only mean that the triangle forms from the other side?

Comment: Well, you have to describe the process.  If the $x-$ coordinate is further than $26$ from the $y-$ axis then the other end of the ladder can't be on the $y-$axis.  There are, of course, interesting curves you can describe  along these lines, like the [hundkurve](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tractrix.html)  that's the curve a dog follows if you are pulling him by a leash while he strains to get at a fixed object out of his reach.

Comment: This is very interesting, for me, at least; I've never considered this at depth. Thank you for the time, really.