# Related Rate Does Not Stay Constant

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, related-rates

If a right triangle with hypotenuse of length $26$ has a leg of length $10$; and this leg (of length 10) is constantly incremented at a speed of $4$ units per second (let "seconds" be considered as another variable t) such that the hypotenuse and right angle are kept constant, at what speed will the remaining leg decrease?

First of all, the remaining leg would, by the Pythagorean Theorem, be of length $24$.

If I solve this as a related rates problem, I would get that, since $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ (let $x = 10$, $y = 24$, $z = 26$), taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $t$ we have: $2x$$dx\over dt$$ + 2y$$dy\over dt$$ = $$2z$$dz\over dt$. Since $z$ is to be kept constant, we have, algebraically: $dy\over dt$$ = –$$x\over y$$dx\over dt$. Substituting $dx\over dt$$ = 4$ and the given intial $x = 10$, $y = 24$ we get $dy\over dt$$ ≈ –1.667$.

Now, to put this to the test, I decided to see if this speed stays constant. Let one unit of $t$ be incremented. Then, $x$ shall be incremented by $4$, and $y$ by approximately $–1.667$. So $x$ shall become $14$, and $y$ approximately shall be $22.334$. However, when I substitute the $x$ and $y$ to our previous equation  $dy\over dt$$ = –$$x\over y$$dx\over dt$. I get, approximately, $dy\over dt$$ = 2.51$. What is going on here? What flaw am I permitting? I believe the speed in which $y$ decreases is supposed to stay constant, but this is not at all what I am observing. Could anyone please point out where I'm making a fallacy? Thank you im advance.

Comment: $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ is constant, but the ratio $\dfrac xy$ changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Related Rates Result Not Precise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4641975/related-rates-result-not-precise)

Comment: @insipidintegrator does this mean that $dy \over dt$ changes? Because it should not be so, since I aquired the result that $dy \over dt$$ = 4$, which is a constant function.

Comment: Your formula for $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is $\frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{x}{y}\frac{dx}{dt} = -4\frac{x}{y}$. If $\frac{dy}{dt}$ is supposed to be constant, then you would have that $x/y$ is a constant. But this isn't true; if that were the case, $y=kx$ for some constant $k$, and you could use the Pythagorean theorem to show that $x$ must also be a constant (and, in fact, your equation in the derivatives shows that $x$ must actually be zero).

Comment: @kamills does this then mean that $y$ will continue decreasing negatively always after $x$ goes beyond $26$? Is this common to all related rate problems, or only specific ones?

Comment: Seriously you reposted the same question without responding to the answer you got the first time?

Comment: @JBL no, that was not the case. The other question asks a different question, though about the same problem. I did not know that the two were actually related. You see, the other question asks why my hypotenuse isn't constant. This one asks why my speed isn't constant. I just now realised that both problems were related in that I assumed the speed was constant. I should delete one of the questions now.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition that the rate of change of $y$ should be constant when $x$ changes at a constant rate is wrong.

To see why, imagine the extreme cases. When $x$ is very small, $y$ is just a little less than the hypotenuse. The leg of length $x$ is nearly perpendicular to hypotenuse, so when it moves it hardly drags the far vertex towards it at all, and the other leg $y$ decreases slowly.

When $x$ is nearly as long as the hypotenuse that leg and the hypotenuse are nearly parallel. Changing $x$ at a constant rate shortens  the other leg rapidly. In fact that rate of decrease increases without bound.

Comment: Does this mean that $dy \over dt$$ ≈ 1.667$ only when $x = 10$? I don't get it, does this also mean that if $x$ still continues increasing constantly by $4$, after $y$ reaches zero, that $y$ will continue speeding up endlessly? Is this phenomena observed in all related rates problems or only in specific ones?

Comment: Yes, these calculations are only valid for one specific instant (one $t$-value). It makes no sense to say that "after $y$ reaches zero, it continues speeding up endlessly" since once $y$ is zero you no longer have a triangle, so the problem is over. This problem is only valid for the $x$-values $0 < x < 26$ (equivalently, $0 < y < 10$). It's not a "phenomenon" so much as it is just remembering that you need to make sure you are considering the domain of the problem.

Comment: Indeed the rate of decrease of $y$ "speeds up endlessly". The linked duplicate question shows that the rate of change of $y$ has a $y$ in the denominator. Please do not post a question twice when you don't like the correct answer you get the first time. This kind of behavior is in fact common in related rate problems. It's what makes them interesting. If the related rates were always just proportional there would be nothing to study.

Comment: @kamills wouldn't "if $x$ goes beyond $26$" simply imply that the triangle forms from the other side? This model would make sense mathematically, only not in certain scenarios physically. However, thank you a lot for this new knowledge; I had no idea! You really don't know how greatful I am!

Comment: @Camelot823 That doesn't quite make sense. The hypotenuse is the longest side of a right triangle, so keeping it fixed at 26, you cannot allow $x$ to reach (or go above) 26 if you want to have a triangle. While you could say that you want to allow $y$ to decrease into negative numbers (e.g. put the triangle on the $xy$-plane), you can do this, but once $x$ reaches 26 to allow $y$ to continue into negative numbers you must start decreasing $x$ from 26 to 0. And, note that you won't have a defined rate of change $dy/dt$ at precisely the point $y=0$, the instant you do not have a triangle.

Comment: @kamills ahh, of course. I now see all the fallacies I haven't considered addressing. Thank you a lot for the illumination! I shall delete this problem now, anyways, to avoid duplicacy